# Como clonar valores de um objeto

Tags: java

Como podemos fazer um objeto igual "valores" de um objeto?

Considerando que meu objeto tem outros objetos, 
e **listas** de outros objetos.

Comment: cria um método Clone que recebe o objeto de Origem e o de Destino e copia os valores que você necessita para o objeto de Destino

Comment: No caso de teres outros objetos lá dentro tens de clona-los também. Se forem listas tens de clonar cada um dos elementos da lista um a um.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há duas opções, basicamente (na verdade três, sendo a terceira "implementar tudo você mesmo"):

1. Implementar a interface [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

   Todo objeto Java possui um método `clone`, capaz de fazer cópias rasas desse objeto. Esse método é `protected`, de modo que normalmente não está acessível. Entretanto, se você fizer com que a classe implemente `Cloneable` e sobrescreva o método `clone` com o modificador `public`, então esse método poderá ser usado para fazer tais cópias (em princípio não precisa sequer implementar nada, o próprio Java faz a "mágica" pra você):

   ```
   public class MinhaClasse implements Cloneable {
       private int x;
       private String y;
       private float z;

       public Object clone() {
           return super.clone();
       }
   }
   ```

   O problema desse método é que, como eu falei, ele faz cópias *rasas* - se você tem referências para outros objetos, e listas de outros objetos, o clone ainda fará referência para os objetos antigos. Por isso acaba sendo necessário implementar lógica própria no método `clone`, o que não é muito conveniente...
2. Serializar seu objeto e depois deserializá-lo em um outro objeto

   Uma opção preferível é usar uma das ferramentas de serialização do Java para transformar seu objeto num array de bytes (ou numa string) e depois transformar isso de volta num objeto. Um meio simples (mas não necessariamente o mais eficiente) é através dos [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) e [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
   oos.writeObject(objeto);

   ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
   Object clone = ois.readObject();
   ```

   Isso fará uma cópia profunda, copiando também cada objeto referenciado, recursivamente, ate que todo o "grafo de objetos" tenha sido copiado (e o que é melhor, mantendo as referências certas, i.e. se `A` aponta pra `B` e `C`, e tanto `B` quanto `C` apontam pra `D`, um único clone de `D` é criado, referenciado pelos clones de `B` e `C`).

   Para isso ser possível, é necessário que sua classe implemente [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), e só. A princípio, nada mais precisa ser feito de sua parte (exceto garantir que todo objeto referenciado *também* implemente `Serializable` - mas muitos dos objetos *built-in* do Java já o fazem).

   Somente tome o cuidado de não serializar mais do que deseja - se seu objeto referencia outros, que referenciam outros, etc, é muito fácil de repente ter a memória inteira do seu programa clonada de uma só vez... Para evitar isso, use o modificador `transient` nos campos que *não devem* ser serializados, e então eles serão ignorados (voltando como `null` após a deserialização):

   ```
   public class MinhaClasse implements Serializable {
       private int x;
       private String y;
       private float z;

       private MinhaOutraClasse a; // Precisa também ser Serializable
       private OutraClasse[] b;    // idem
       private transient NaoCloneEsta c; // Não precisa ser, tanto faz
   }
   ```